# I'm getting no response from this command: rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0

Tags: ros, roscore, rosserial-python, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I'm getting to know ROS with arduino programming, and I'm struggling to run ROS as I complete the first tutorial of [Hello world](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World) . Roscore seems to work because the terminal begins outputting summary and Nodes but then when I input: rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0

Nothing happens, not even an error message. It's like I input a newline. I'm not sure what this means or what it could imply.
I know for sure my usb port is located in /dev/ttyACM0 , it's the address located on my Arduino IDE which works.

I'm using Mac to run Virtual Box Ubuntu (latest), and have ROS Kinetic installed along with arduino IDE.
I also have catkin workstation installed.
This was the setup instructed prior to trying out hello world.

If there's any info needed to solve this, I'll be be happy to answer asap.
It hurts I can't do the first tutorial

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281175/i%27m-getting-no-response-from-this-command:-rosrun-rosserial_python-serial_node.py-/dev/ttyacm0/) by [patr1ckt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33442/patr1ckt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-30**:
may you try only this  rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py
after uploading sketch into Arduino

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-30**:
I don't think you should receive any Output from the command, if all goes as planned.
If you follow the tutorial, you should open a new terminal and call: `rostopic echo chatter`. This should produce Output. Do you do this?

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-30**:
yes i done this tell me step wise what have you done briefly

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-31**:
@patr1ckt: how is this a duplicate question? If it is, of what other question?

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-31**:
you get answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you guys. Mig, you are right in that for each of these commands, I must open a new terminal. The tutorial only states to open a new terminal once where actually, it must be done for each individual command. Thanks for your help!

---

Originally posted by [patr1ckt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33442/patr1ckt/) with karma: 16 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0